# What is the easiest method to construct a bezier curve for the half part of a symmetric bezier curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote

Consider the following symmetric (about vertical axis) bezier curve constructed by 4 points `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. Now I want to construct another bezier curve (named `L`) for just either the left or right part of it.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,-1)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode
        (3,3){A}
        (1,1){B}
        (-1,1){C}
        (-3,3){D}
    \psbezier(A)(B)(C)(D)
    \psline[linecolor=red](0,3)(0,-1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without solving a polynomial equation first, how can I construct the bezier curve `L`? Answers with PSTricks (preferred) or TikZ or Asymptote are welcome.

Note that I hate a trial and error method!

Comment: Is it specifically this curve and only the half of it or more general?

Comment: @percusse: `\psbezier` can only accept 4 points at most so @g.kov solution is enough. No need to expand for higher-order bezier curves consisting of more than 4 points.

Comment: PDF doesn't support higher order anyway. I meant is this specific to these curves or arbitrary curves?

Comment: @percusse: I don't understand you. The given 4 points can be changed to any numbers as long as its curve is symmetrical about vertical axis. :-)

Comment: See, we have a constraint of symmetricity? Do you have others that's what I asked.

Comment: @percusse: No. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Here is the `Asymptote` version, which does not use
the general `Asymptote` commands to split a path (guide),
it just performs a simple subdivision of the cubic `Bezier` segment:

```
// split.asy: 

size(5cm);
pair A,B,C,D;
A=(3,3); B=(1,1); C=(-1,1); D=(-3,3);

pair P,B1,C1,B2,C2;

P=(A+D+3(B+C))/8;

B1 = (A+B)/2;
C1 = ((A+C)/2+B)/2;
C2 = (D+C)/2;
B2 = ((D+B)/2+C)/2;

guide g=A..controls B and C..D;
guide gl=A..controls B1 and C1..P;
guide gr=P..controls B2 and C2..D;
draw(g);
draw(gl,deepgreen+1.6bp+opacity(0.5));
draw(gr,red+1.6bp+opacity(0.5));
draw((0,3)--(0,-1),red);

dot(A--B--C--D--P,UnFill);
dot(B1--C1,deepgreen,UnFill);
dot(B2--C2,red,UnFill);
label("$A$",A,SE);
label("$B$",B,S);
label("$C$",C,S);
label("$D$",D,SW);
label("$P$",P,NE);
label("$B_1$",B1,E,deepgreen);
label("$C_1$",C1,E,deepgreen);
label("$B_2$",B2,W,red);
label("$C_2$",C2,W,red);
```

To get a standalone `split.pdf`, run `asy -f pdf split.asy`.

Comment: I really need the converting formulae.

Comment: @Stiff Jokes: Btw, the `Bezier` curve is a very interesting object, you might enjoy studying it in a spare time.

Answer (score 5):

A translated version for @g.kov's Asymptote answer in PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3,-1)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode
        (3,3){A}
        (1,1){B}
        (-1,1){C}
        (-3,3){D}
    \psbezier(A)(B)(C)(D)
    \psline[linecolor=red](0,3)(0,-1)
    \nodexn{.125(A)+.125(D)+.375(B)+.375(C)}{R'}
    \nodexn{.5(A)+.5(B)}{P'}
    \nodexn{.25(A)+.5(B)+.25(C)}{Q'}
    \pstGeonode
        (P'){P}
        (Q'){Q}
        (R'){R}
    \psbezier[linecolor=red](A)(P)(Q)(R)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The conversion formulae seems to be scary.

Comment: The conversion formula has a nice geometric interpretation: see http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Bezier-curves.html#Bezier-curves